# ASP.NET MVC master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

In a custom viewengine in the findview method the mastername is always empty, even if the page has a masterpage defined.
Any idea why, or how can I get the mastername?

In the viewEngine class:

```
MasterLocationFormats = new[] {
    "~/{0}.master",
    "~/Shared/{0}.master",
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.master"
};

public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache) { }
```

In the page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Empty.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

The master file exists.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that your master page is not in standard location ? Can you post some code of your Custom viewengine ?

Answer (score 0):

Debra, if the action method which returns the View specifically mentions the masterpage name (e.g. return View("viewName", "masterName")), FindView will try to find it in the locations specified in the MasterLocationFormats array and assign it as the view's masterpage. This masterpage would override the masterpage specified in page directives.

If, on the other hand, masterpage is not specified by the action method, FindView will not look for it, either as it does not know about it. It is only at the time of rendering the page where ViewEngine picks up the master page name from page directives and renders it with the rest of the page.

Hope it helps.